# Assigning static device path

Tags: rhel, boot, usb, path, devices

I have 4 flash cards plugged in, sequentially named by system:

- /dev/sda1
- /dev/sdb1
- /dev/sdc1
- /dev/sdd1

I want to assign static pathes to them, so every time the system boots up their pathes will not change, no matter in what order they are plugged in.

I think it should be possible to assign static path directly to device **UUID**.

The OS I am running is *Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [write udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) to create a symlink to each.